# Como validar una fecha correctamente con SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, simpledateformat

tengo este codigo y en un cierto caso si me regresa la excepcion de que existe un error para calcular la vigencia y en otra ocacion me muestra que esta mal el parseo alguien me puede explicar porque? y como resolverlo?

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
           formatoFecha.setLenient(false);
           try {
               if(!("".equals(fecHasta)))
               {
                   formatoFecha.parse(fecHasta);
               }
               }catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException(clienteId,
                    AppMessages.ERROR_RANGO_FECHAS,
                    this.getClass().getSimpleName());
              }
```

alguna vez me devuelve
1.- Con la fecha:"fecHasta": "2028-0767-04"

```
"codigoResultado": "ERROR1",
  "descripcion": "CONSULTA_NO_EXITOSA",
  "motivo": "ERROR FECHAS"
```

2.- con la fecha:"fecHasta": "22028-07-04"

```
{
  "codigoResultado": "ERROR1",
  "descripcion": "CONSULTA_NO_EXITOSA",
  "motivo": "01=Text '22028-07-04' could not be parsed at index 0",
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué el catch está dentro del try? ¿Eso compila?

Comment: disculpa el catch si esta fuera solo que cuando copie y legue lo hice mal esque recorte 2 validaciones mas que hacen lo mismpo deja edito el codigo

Comment: Bueno, incluso aunque pongas yyyy con la vieja api de fechas te tomará el año como válido. Mi recomendación es, usa `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(fecHasta);` en lugar de la vieja api de fechas de java. Eso te funcionará perfectamente. PD: Asumo que estás en java >= 8